# how can I rearrange this code so my setInterval stops looping infinitely?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to make a simple flip-card/memory match (like from super mario brothers 3) game in HTML/Javascript and am having a slight issue with the setInterval command.

Here is a link to the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/msfZj/
Here is the main issue/main logic of it:

```
if(click == 2)  //denotes two cards being clicked
{
    if(flippedArray[1].src === flippedArray[0].src)  // if click 1 == click 2 then refer to function 'delayMatch' which sets click 1 and 2 cards to not be displayed
    {
        window.setInterval(function() { delayMatch() }, 500);       
        console.log("EQUAL");

    }
    else
    {
        window.setInterval(function() { delayNoMatch() }, 500); // if click 1 != click 2 then display card.png 
        console.log("NOT EQUAL");

    }
        function delayMatch()  //function for matching pairs
    {
    flippedArray[0].style = "display:none;";
    flippedArray[1].style = "display:none;";

    }
        function delayNoMatch()  //function for non-matching pairs
    {
    flippedArray[0].src = "card.png";
    flippedArray[1].src = "card.png";   
    }


    click = 0;  // when clicked two cards set click back to zero    
}
```

The first two cards I click on always work: but from that point onward the setInterval keeps running the function over and over again in an endless loop every 500ms.

I'd be extremely appreciative if anybody can point my in the right direction on how I can do this properly.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need `setTimeout`, which only runs once?

```
window.setTimeout(function() { delayMatch() }, 500);
```

Otherwise, you need to clear the interval with `clearInterval(i)`, but first set "i" using the return value of `setInterval`:

```
var i = window.setInterval(function() { delayMatch() }, 500);
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UKfhr/11/) (I JQuerified it a bit for JSFiddle).

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to go with setTimeout() instead of setInterval()

A handy function when you use setTimeout is clearTimeout. Say you want to set a timer, but maybe want a button to cancel

```
var timer = setTimeout(fn,1000);

//later maybe
clearTimeout(timer);
```